# Contains only "string" with regex

Tags: regex

```
lolhellolol
hellohello
hello
hello+1
```

I'm looking for all strings that match `hello` EXACTLY and nothing else. I don't want strings that contain `hello`. How would I do this with regex?

Comment: This question is currently too unclear to answer. *Why* would you want only the first string to be selected? Are you actually just looking for strings which contain "lolhellolol"?

Comment: What is the "unique" property of that first string? Do you only want strings that contain `"hello"` only once?

Comment: `^hello$` would look for `hello` **only**.

Comment: I'm looking for all strings that match `hello` EXACTLY and nothing else. I don't want strings that contain `hello`.

Comment: no regex is needed here. `if $string eq 'hello'` would do the job.

Comment: @M42, I have to use regex for this one :P

Comment: as Cthulhu said, `^hello$`

Comment: @Cthulhu not working for http://regexpal.com/. Tried with my data.

Comment: @meiryo Check the `match at line breaks (m)` option on top.

Comment: @meiryo: Make sure you check _"^$ match at line breaks (m)"_

Comment: Noted, thanks. Also why are my questions getting downvoted?

Comment: Perhaps because this is something you should have studied under regex basics. If you are using JS, your regex would be `/^hello$/m`.

Comment: I see. I did try `^hello$` before posting this question but the regex site didn't give the results I wanted. Thanks for the tip regardless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you *only*  want to match `hello`:

```
^hello$
```

However, it is most likely a better idea to use your language's syntax to do something like:

```
if(myString == "hello"){}          // JavaScript // Ruby
if($myString == "hello"){}         // php
if(myString.equals("hello"))       // Java / C#
IF %myString == "hello"            // Batch
if(strcmp(myString, "hello") == 0) // C++
if myString == "hello":
    //Do something                 // Python
// You get the idea.
```

Answer (score 3):

The regex would be

```
^hello$
```

But I would simply use your app code to test if the string equals "hello", no regex needed.

```
java: if (s.equals("hello"))
shell: if [ $s -eq "hello" ];
JavaScript: if ( s == "hello" )
```

etc. I could go on. Perhaps others would like to add other language's versions. Actually I'd love to see how many languages we could code the test in